# How to create a gradient shape that blurs on one side?

Tags: color, gradient, blur

How do I achieve the effect in the pictures below where the shape is defined on one side and the shape and gradient blur on the other? (I hope i'm even describing it right)

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: Please let us know what you tried, where you're stuck etc.

Comment: It would depend upon what software you are using.

Comment: I believe you are a beginner who has no idea how to start. Regardless of coming downvotes I write one answer before the question is closed.

Comment: Yeah you're right @user287001! I was trying to think of ways on how I could do it on Photoshop or trying to search it on google or youtube but didn't know what to call it. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One receipe for Photoshop. The result is a bitmap:

1. Have a simple shape with gradient fill on a black background:

[image]

2. Apply Filters > Blur > Radial Blur > Spin, put the spin center near one edge of the shape

[image]

3. Apply Filters > Blur > Radial Blur > Zoom

[image]

4. Make a selection with polygonal lasso tool and clean the edge. Note that the blur covers large area, have a wide selection

[image]

5. Duplicate the shape layer to have enough density

[image]