# How can I recreate this cast light effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, blur

I've been trying to reproduce the light from the "hole" on Illustrator but I still can’t achieve this effect[image]

Comment: Have you tried a gradient with an Opacity Mask to feather the edges ? The hole part can be done with a clipping mask or even black shapes overlaid on the gradient. What part are you having difficulty with ? Photoshop would be my first choice to do this. The feathering could be done with a soft brush on a mask.

Comment: I agree with Kyle, maybe in your case it does make sense to use Illustrator, but I'd do it in Photoshop, since it doesn't look like the background image is vector... a little bit of vector graphics on top of a bitmap isn't a huge benefit. And freeform gradients/masks are way easier in PS.

Comment: A Photoshop version is known: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105678/how-to-create-a-gradient-shape-that-blurs-on-one-side

Answer (score 2):

It could easily be pulled off with a **Gradient Mesh** in Illustrator.

[image]

If you are unfamiliar with Gradient Meshes, starting with the [Adobe Help Files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html) is good in order to understand the base functionality. Then merely search for tutorials on using the Gradient Mesh. There are several on YouTube.

Comment: P.D. Add a second gradient mesh for the shadow. ;)

Comment: Yes and possibly two feathered stroked paths for the two highlights `:)`